# for loop question in r :number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

all

I'm new to R. I try many ways and still cannot solve it. Can anyone help to check??

I am trying to produce 3 times 100 random values that follow a chisquare  distribution. Console says ''number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length''. Any hint to fix it??

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  x1[i] <- rchisq(100, df=2)
  n1[i] <- length(x1[i])
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?
`for(i in 1:3){
x1 <- rchisq(100, df=2)
n1 <- length(x1)
print(x1[n1])
}`

Comment: Try using double-square brackets: `x1[[i]] <- rchisq(100, df=2)`

Answer (score 1):

As an explanation for your problem: You are trying to store a vector of 100 elements into a single element, the `i`th element, of a vector, `x1`. To illustrate, you could put a vector of values into a vector of the same length:

```
x <- rnorm(6, 0, 1)
x[1:3] <- c(1,2,3)
x
## [1]  1.0000000  2.0000000  3.0000000 -0.8652300  1.3776699 -0.8817483
```

You could to store them into a list, each element of a list is a vector that can be of any length. You will need double square brackets.

```
x1 <- list()
for(i in 1:3) {
  x1[[i]] <- rchisq(100, df=2)
  n1[i] <- length(x1[[i]])
}
```

Lists and vectors are different types of data structures in R, you can read a lot about them in [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Comment: You will want double brackets inside the length() function on the list element

Comment: Well spotted - thanks. Thought I had done that but must have forgot!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what containers you want to use. There are two containers that come to mind, either a list or matrix.

```
# list format
x1 = list();
n1 = vector();
for(i in 1:3) {
  x1[[i]] <- rchisq(100, df=2)
  n1[i] <- length(x1[[i]])
}
```

note the double brackets `[[i]]` as mentioned in the comments

```
# matrix format
x1 = matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 3)
n1 = vector();
for(i in 1:3) {
  x1[,i] <- rchisq(100, df=2)
  n1[i] <- length(x1[,i])
}
```

Comment: @linlin If it answers your question, can you mark the question correct. Cheers